# Netty GlobalChannelTrafficShapingHandler for multiple channels

Tags: netty

The [document](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/traffic/GlobalChannelTrafficShapingHandler.html) says

> Note that this handler has a Pipeline Coverage of "all" which means
>   only one such handler must be created and shared among all channels as
>   the counter must be shared among all channels.

I understand this handler must be shared.

Suppose I have two groups of channels.  **Can I use different `GlobalChannelTrafficShapingHandler` instance for each group?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In case those groups are not intersect you are fine (do not share same channels).
You can have a look into code a see that `GlobalChannelTrafficShapingHandler` has own non static `channelQueues` field that holds all channels within pipelines it was added to. 
So in other words - `GlobalChannelTrafficShapingHandler` doesn't hold any shared stated across all instances (no any static shared fields). You are free to create few instances.